# psql query returns blank rows

Tags: postgresql, psql

I store data from django in a postgreSQL database. My data is a huge nested list of floats with about 3 thousand rows. It looks like this:

```
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], 
[0.3, 0.5, 0.6], 
[0.7, 0.8 0.9]]
```

I tried to query it in pgAdmin 4, but it gives an output with a huuge delay. Now I am trying to query it with psql and it gives out only blank rows.
my query:

```
SELECT * FROM public."abc" LIMIT 1;
```

what I get:

```
 id |
```

and then a lot of blank rows.

Comment: We need 1) Table definition, in particular the data type for the field you are trying to retrieve 2) Result of `SELECT * FROM public."abc" where id is not NULL LIMIT 1; 3) Connection parameters for `pgAdmin` vs `psql` to confirm you are connecting to same database. Add answers as update to question.

Comment: Hi, 
2) I got the same blank lines
3) same parameters for both: server: localhost, database: test, port: 6000, username: postgres
1) I'm not sure what you mean here. I am using a nested list with floats. In django model, I save it as an Arrayfield.

Comment: Then either:  1) The data did not get saved/committed to the database 2) You are pointing at wrong database or table in the database when you do the queries. Look at the Postgres log at the time you inserted the data in Django to see if there are any clues.

Comment: I think it's just a formatting issue.  The second column is so wide that the label isn't displayed until you get past what appear to be many black lines.  Having such a huge list does not seem like a good design...

Comment: @Jeremy yes, I think it is rather a formatting issue (though I couldn't get the to the end of the blank lines...) Thanks